# file_get_contents don't work with a while

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a very simple PHP code. It work great but if i write a while the file_get_contents don't work all time and i need continue refresh the page for start work it.

This is my code:

```
$counter = 0;
$counter2 = 20;
$content = file_get_contents("THEURL");
// sleep(2);

while($counter < $counter2)
{
   $counter++;
   $first_step = explode( '<h2 class="rgs">' , $content ); 
   $second_step = explode("</h2>" , $first_step[$counter] );
   // echo $second_step[0];
   $link[$counter] = htmlspecialchars($second_step[0]);
   // echo "$link";
   // echo "<br>";
}
```

if i remove the while, all work good.
Everyone can help me to fix this?

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you trying to parse `html` with `explode`? Also, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: A first step, as the code stands: Move `$first_step = ...` out of the while-loop (above it).

Comment: $link is only a variable for me where after i substr it for get a specific value. One host can have a multiple  file_get_contents in two different .php pages at the same time?

Comment: More times the error is: Warning: file_get_contents(MYURL): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /usr/local/psa/home/vhosts/tncitalia.com/httpdocs/SNMP/extractorlombardia.php on line 22
But if i refresh the page more time, it work. Why?

Comment: That means your file has incorrect permissions. Read more here: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions